# Puppeteer can't find the element

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I've been trying to make puppeteer get the login button on a task planner account, but it returns an error "PS C:\Users\leticia.queiroz\Visual Studio> node Teste2.js
(node:14920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector"

The code i'm submitting is:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://tasks.office.com/')
  await page.click('#plannerSignInButton')
  await page.waitForSelector('input[id="i0116"]', {
    visible: true,
  });
  await page.click('input[id="i0116"]')
  await page.type('input[id="i0116"]','user@example.login.com')
  await browser.close();
})()
```

The html code i get from the developer insights are:

```
<input type="email" name="loginfmt" id="i0116" maxlength="113" class="form-control ltr_override input ext-input text-box ext-text-box" aria-required="true" data-bind="
                    attr: { lang: svr.fApplyAsciiRegexOnInput ? null : 'en' },
                    externalCss: {
                        'input': true,
                        'text-box': true,
                        'has-error': usernameTextbox.error },
                    ariaLabel: tenantBranding.unsafe_userIdLabel || str['CT_PWD_STR_Username_AriaLabel'],
                    ariaDescribedBy: 'loginHeader' + (pageDescription &amp;&amp; !svr.fHideLoginDesc ? ' loginDescription usernameError' : ' usernameError'),
                    textInput: usernameTextbox.value,
                    hasFocusEx: usernameTextbox.focused,
                    placeholder: $placeholderText" aria-label="Insira o seu email, telefone ou Skype." aria-describedby="loginHeader usernameError" placeholder="Email, telefone ou Skype">
```

Comment: Are you absolutely positive the `id` is always `i0116`? Seems like it’d be dynamically-generated to me.

Comment: Yep, i checked again and in another computer, it's the same.

Comment: What happens if you add a `waitForSelector` before your `click` of `#plannerSignInButton`? Seems like it's possible your code could advance before the button is present in the DOM.

Comment: it works! i get an screenshot of the `click`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is moving too quickly and trying to click the button `#plannerSignInButton` before it's available in the DOM. Add and `await` the return value of a `waitForSelector` immediately beforehand:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://tasks.office.com/')
  await page.waitForSelector('#plannerSignInButton');
  await page.click('#plannerSignInButton')
  await page.waitForSelector('input[id="i0116"]', {
    visible: true,
  });
  await page.click('input[id="i0116"]')
  await page.type('input[id="i0116"]','user@example.login.com')
  await browser.close();
})()
```